# Returning all objects generated within a function

Tags: r, function, output

I want to write a function that returns a list of all of the (internally generated) objects. I have attempted to use `ls() %>% mget()` or `get`, but I get the error `Error: value for ‘xxx’ not found`. I'm pretty sure the issues is with the `pos`/`environment` arguments, but I can't figure out the solution. Here is my code:

```
library(magrittr)

types <- c("Mouse", "Cage", "Mating") %>% magrittr::set_names(., .)

tmp1 <- types %>% 
  lapply(function(type) list(type = type)) %>% 
  lapply(function(lst) {
    type <- lst$type
    regex <- paste0("prefix_", type, "_suffix")
    ls() %>% mget()
  })

tmp2 <- types %>% 
  lapply(function(type) list(type = type)) %>% 
  lapply(function(lst) {
    type <- lst$type
    regex <- paste0("prefix_", type, "_suffix")
    ls() %>% lapply(get)
  })

tmp3 <- types %>% 
  lapply(function(type) list(type = type)) %>% 
  lapply(function(lst) {
    type <- lst$type
    regex <- paste0("prefix_", type, "_suffix")
    list(
      type = type,
      regex = regex
    )
  })
```

`tmp3` gives the desired output. However, I don't want to have to edit the `list(...)` section every time I modify the function to produce additional intermediate objects. Thanks.

Comment: Something of the form `mget(grep("type",ls(),value = TRUE))` will return a list of objects matching the Regex pattern, is that what you're going for?

Comment: The output I want is `list(type = type, regex = regex)` in this case, but might be `list(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d)` in another case. I want all of the objects in the function environment.

Comment: Perhaps try `types %>%  lapply(function(type) {
    regex <- paste0("prefix_", type, "_suffix");
    mget(ls())
  })`

Comment: change `ls()%>%mget()` to `mget(ls())` I cant tell why the former doesnot work

Comment: `mget(ls())` works. Does using the magrittr pipe operator create a new child environment in which `mget` is called?

Comment: @Josh - seems to be the case.  Using `ls() %>% mget(inherits = TRUE)` or `ls() %>% mget(envir = parent.frame())` both work.

Comment: If you want to pipe, the base pipe works fine, `ls() |> mget()` (because it's just syntactical sugar, not needing to mess with environments)

Comment: I had forgotten about the new base pipe.